# Вывод всех картинок из поста в определенное место (WordPres)?

Tags: php, wordpress

1. Как вывести все картинки из текущего поста в определенное место.   ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
2. У меня есть боковой блок я хочу туда вывести
3. в **html обёртке** все картинки из текущего поста.

По умолчанию **в редакторе WordPress** картинки выводятся в месте, где выводится текст **the_content()**

**Вот скрин:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

⠀⠀⠀

- **Каким образом вывести все картинки из текущего поста в определенное место в html-обёртке**

  ***Как на скрине:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Мой код файла **single.php:**

```js
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php the_post(); ?>

 <main class="Main_ContentKg"> 
  
 <article class="Text_Main_Block">   
  
<h1 class ="first_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<br>
<?php the_content(); ?>

 </article>
  
 </main>
   

 <aside class="Main_SidebarKg"> 

 <section class="Sidebar_Main_Block">
   

   
<!-- ******** КАК сюда вывести картинки, которые находятся в текущей записи ******** --> 
 
<!-- ******** Html обёртка ********

<figure class="Sidebar_block_1"> 

<img class="Sidebar_Img" src="img/Post_sidebar/3.jpeg">

<figcaption class ="Sidebar_Img_text">

Ученые из Университета Карнеги 
и Университета штата Миннесота впервые в истории 
создали неинвазивный нейроинтерфейсный протез руки.

</figcaption> 

</figure> 
 ******** Конец html-обёртки ******** -->
 

 
 </section>

 </aside>
 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте для поста создал галерею, куда и положил бы все картинки с подписями. А дальше вопрос трансформируется в то, как вывести галерею с картинками внутри произвольного места в посте. Тут могут быть несколько вариантов, смотря какой редактор вы используете и смотря какой подход, classic editor или gutenberg. Если classic editor, то там можно получить галерею через get_post_gallery(), если gutenberg, то в гутенберге в самом редакторе можно собрать нужную html-структуру. Если же вы не захотите собирать в гутенберге нужную структуру то придется парсить галерею - но такой подход боль

Comment: Я тоже думал про галерею, но там нельзя оборачивать в свою html-обёртку. Там уже идет своя готовая html-обёртка, можно лишь менять стили у галерей и все. Даже если получится обёрнуть в свою html-обёртку все это дело придется выводить циклом? Но каким циклом? Я знаю лишь цикл для вывода постов и все =(

Comment: И еще в gutenberg вручную придется в каждом посте собирать нужную html-структуру верно?

Comment: Вам нужно понять, что есть несколько подходов: вы пытаетесь, как я понял, залезть в файл шаблона и организовать в нем нужную структуру руками (вывести циклы там где и нужно и пр) При таком подходе, используя classic editor  спомощью ф-ии get_post_gallery() можно получить массив с данными галереи поста и уже из этого массива вытащить все что нужно и собрать нужную структуру. Есть и другие подходы, например, используя редактор гутенберг и тему KADENCE (вроде в премиум версии фишек много всяких) можно руками собрать в редакторе, что нужно.

Comment: Также есть такая вещь как блоки гутенберга и можно реализовать свой свой собственный блок, но это может быть сложно. Использовать classic editor - это устаревший подход, исп-ть гутенберг и блоки гутенберга - современный подход. Можно также организовать динамичный шорткод для вывода циклов различных, на wp-plus на ютуб можно посмотреть (вообще там много годноты). Иными словами, необязательно лезть в файл шаблонов, есть и другие пути.